# Django template lookup does not look in the app

Tags: django, django-templates

[Uber simple app](https://github.com/ripper234/Web2Workflowy/tree/first-template). My views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    #return HttpResponse("Ready to turn some webpages into workflowies?")
    template = loader.get_template('web/index.html')

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

I'm trying to get my first template to render, and I get

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\utils\python\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\web\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\utils\python\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\web\index.html (Source does not exist)
```

Why doesn't the loader find the template in `/web/templates/index.html`?

Comment: IMO the loader will look for `/templates/web/index.html`

Comment: You are loading `'web/index.html'` but expect `/web/templates/index.html`. If `web` is an app, you need to add it in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py`. Also, the directory structure for the templates should be `web/templates/web/index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

You place index.html in /web/templates/web/index.html. It will work. In settings.py please add web app to

```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'web',
```

]